# Windows service only executes once

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, topshelf

I've written my first .Net Service using [TopShelf](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html) and I'm experiencing an issue where the service code only executes a single time.

I have configured the service main as follows

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<ServiceProcess>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new ServiceProcess());
                s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
                s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
            });

            x.StartAutomatically();
            x.RunAs(Username, Password);
        });
    }
```

And the method that runs only a single time is as follows.

```
using System.Timers;

public class ServiceProcess
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public ServiceProcess()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000) { AutoReset = false };
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName, "It is " + DateTime.Now, EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
}
```

I can see in the event log that the message is written correctly but it only occurs a single time.  Since this is the most basic of configuration I'm not certain why this isn't working.  I have played with the timing and attempted to add exception handling but ultimately it appears to simply not be running again.

Note that my `Start()` and `Stop()` methods are doing a `_timer.Start()` and `_timer.Stop()` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set AutoReset property of your timer to true.

Comment: In my defense I was given bad information by a coworker.  ;)  Happy to give you the easy points.

Comment: I wanted to provide this link for anyone looking.  This is not specific to TopShelf but is a service property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx